# How to add accepts to bindFormRequest with multiples values?

Tags: playframework-2.1

Using PlayFramework 2.1.1, I have a form that contains (with other fields) :

```
@repeat(form("websites"), min=3){elementField =>
    <div class="entry">
        @inputUrl(elementField("display"), '_showConstraints -> false, 'placeholder -> "Url", 'class -> "span4")
        @helper.select(elementField("type.id"), helper.options(models.WebsiteType.listAsOptions), '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "span2")
    </div>
}
```

Now, I'd like to set which fields I'll accept in my controller, but how can I accept theses fields since I don't know how many of them will be submitted ?

```
String[] accepts = { "display", "email", "websites[].display", "websites[].type.id",};
Form<MyModel> form = Form.form(MyModel.class).bindFromRequest(accepts);
```

Moreover, setting `accepts` or not in bindFormRequest doesn't work, when I call form.get().getWebsites(), this is always empty.

So, can you help me with these two problems?

1. Is it possible to add a multiples values in an accept array for bindFromRequest ?
2. Why getWebsites() is always empty (not associated)

Thank you for your help !